# Routing table with more devices

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, routing-table

**I need a connection:**
laptop (windows) 192.168.10.102     ->      router 192.168.10.10        -> (Int: eth0) RPI 192.168.10.17 (Int: docker0) -> (Int:eth0) docker 172.17.0.2 (Int:tun0) ->  (Int:tun0) other device 192.168.255.10

**My route table on RPI:**

```
rafal@raspberrypi:~ $ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.10   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.255.0   172.17.0.2      255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 docker0
```

**My route table on docker:**

```
bash-4.3# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.17.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.254.0   192.168.255.2   255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
192.168.255.0   192.168.255.2   255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
192.168.255.2   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
```

Laptop and RPI are connected to router gateway.
RPI pinging 172.17.0.2 succeeded
RPI pinging 192.168.255.10 succeeded

I configured route on router, but laptop return timeout:

```
PS C:\Users\Rafał> tracert 192.168.255.10
Tracing route to 192.168.255.10 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     3 ms     2 ms     2 ms  192.168.10.10
  2     5 ms     2 ms     2 ms  192.168.10.17
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  (...)
```

I think that the problem is RPI route table.

How route should be added to RPI route table?
Whats going wrong?

Comment: when  you say "router 192.168.10.10" are you talking about using the switch ports for the router LAN interface, or is another interface (like WAN) involved? note that you cannot route traffic between two router interfaces (lan, wan, etc) that have the same IP network running on them (based on IP  address).   "laptop (windows) 192.168.10.102 -> router 192.168.10.10 -> (Int: eth0) RPI 192.168.10.17" is fine if they are all plugged into ports on the same interface (like the LAN interface on a standard consumer grade router), where its just switching, not routing.

Comment: Laptop and RPI is connected to the same LAN interface of router device.

Comment: You want to rethink this - your whole described setup looks very impractical - 192.168.10.102 -> router 192.168.10.10 -> (Int: eth0) RPI 192.168.10.17 is very difficullt to pull off, and would require subnetting 192.168.10.  You really need to put different networks in different ranges.     Maybe worth taking a course in Networking 101 to learn about subnets, networking, hairpin nat and routing.

Comment: Tnx for last reply, I changed my network with your suggestion and I have similar problem:
https://superuser.com/questions/1811149/openvpn-site-to-side-tunel-with-specific-client